# Is outrageous rate translated by taux scandaleux in this context?

Tags: traduction, anglais

> Euler’s total work output accounts for a third of all that was
> published in Europe on mathematics, theoretical physics, mechanics,
> and engineering mechanics from 1726 to 1800. He produced it at an
> **outrageous rate**, publishing more than any other single mathematician
> before or after him. If quality of output multiplied by quantity of
> output is equal to greatness, then Euler is the greatest mathematician
> ever.
>
> Le travail d’Euler représente un tiers de la totalité des
> publications en Europe sur les mathématiques, la physique théorique,
> la mécanique et la mécanique technique de 1726 à 1800. Il a produit à
> un **taux scandaleux**, en publiant plus que tout autre mathématicien
> seul avant ou après lui. Si la qualité de la production
> multipliée par la quantité de la production est égale à la grandeur,
> Euler est le plus grand mathématicien de tous les temps.

Does taux scandaleux Interprets correctly outrageous rate in this context?

Comment: *Si la qualité de la production multipliée par la quantité de la production est égale à la grandeur* pourrait être amélioré en *Si l'on mesure la grandeur d'une œuvre en calculant le produit de sa quantité par celui de sa qualité*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est bon. Merci !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non, ce n'est certainement pas « scandaleux » ; en anglais, dans ce cas particulier « outrageous  » signifie  « enormous, extaordinary » (énorme, extraordinaire) ; le mot à de nombreuses acceptions;

> Oxford dictionary: 1. immoderate, intemperate, extravagant; enormous, extraordinary;
>   2. Unrestrained in action, violent, furious 3. Excessively injurious or cruel; of the nature of a violent wrong or offence; grossely immoral or offensive.

Une bonne traduction de base serait « extraordinaire ».

Néanmoins la traduction de « rate » par « taux » ne convient pas ; le mot « rythme » convient ; donc une traduction de base serait « **rythme extaordinaire** ».
On peut cependant utiliser d'autres termes qui décrivent cela. Par exemple « **rythme infernal** » est une possibilité.

> infernal (TLFi) Qui a quelque chose de démesuré, d'excessif. Entêtement, orgueil, culot, sans gêne, rythme infernal; curiosité, complexité infernale.