# « C'est simplement outrageant » : un faux « faux-ami » en contexte ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, comparaison-de-langues, faux-amis

> "It's just [**outrageous**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outrageous), there's no other word to describe it,"
>   said John English, who wrote an acclaimed biography of Trudeau. "It's
>   a tragedy that this has happened, and I think the explanation is
>   weak." ([Cbc.ca](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/pierre-trudeau-csis-file-1.5177205))
>
> ---
>
> « C'est simplement **outrageant**. Il n'y a pas d'autres mots pour
>   décrire cela, a commenté John English, auteur d'une biographie fort
>   réputée de l'ancien premier ministre fédéral. Leur justification est
>   faible. » ([LaPresse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/201906/15/01-5230307-le-scrs-a-detruit-un-dossier-sur-pierre-elliott-trudeau.php))

Y avait-il un autre mot en [français](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/outrageous/599506) ? Évidemment, M. English s'est exprimé en anglais et le mot [*outrageant*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/outrageant/0), « qui constitue un [outrage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/outrage/0) » (et même *outrageux*, insistant sur la nature de l'action plutôt que sur l'action elle-même nous dit le TLFi) existe en français. Il n'est pas difficile de trouver d'autres termes assez typiquement employés pour traduire en français mais j'aimerais savoir jusqu'à quel point il y a intersection de ceux-ci avec *outrageant*, lequel ou lesquels sont les plus usuels vu la réaction de M. English, le contexte (la réaction à la perte d'un élément historique relevant d'un personnage politique important au Canada ; il existe d'autres types de [contexte](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32980/19187)) et le ton/langage employé dans l'article et si l'emploi d'*outrageant* se justifie ici néanmoins : s'agit-il d'un « faux » faux-ami ?

Answer (score 3):

*Outrageant* ne me semble pas déplacé et a le mérite de la proximité.

Il ne fait cependant pas partie des adjectifs que j'emploierai spontanément. Il a un petit soupçon d'anglicisme, mais d'un autre côté, le mot est bien français et le sens attendu me semble compatible.

J'aurais donc probablement utilisé autre chose comme :

> C'est proprement scandaleux,...
>
> C'est absolument révoltant,...

*Révoltant* me semble plus fort que *scandaleux* et *outrageant*, et ce dernier plus adapté à des insultes, des grossièretés au sens propre, alors qu'il faut le prendre est au sens figuré dans l'affaire en question.

Comment: *Outrageant* ne fait pas partie des adjectifs que j'emploierai spontanément. Il a un petit soupçon d'anglicisme, mais d'un autre côté, le mot est bien français et le sens attendu me semble compatible. Je trouve *révoltant* plus fort que *scandaleux* et *outrageant*, et ce dernier plus adapté à des insultes, des grossièretés au sens propre, alors que c'est au sens figuré dans l'affaire en question. PS: Quand j'ai lu *Évidemment, M. English s'est exprimé en anglais*, j'ai d'abord cru à une blague ;-)

Comment: Des Français en France, il y en a mais c'est un patronyme rare, probablement moins d'un millier. Il y a eu un *[François Français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Fran%C3%A7ais)* et il en a probablement encore...

Comment: +1 à révoltant ou scandaleux. Commettre un outrage, en français, c'est insulter ou manquer de respect. Tandis qu'en anglais quelque chose de *outrageous*, c'est un motif d'indignation plus général que cela. En particulier on peut trouver que la situation d'un tiers soit révoltante ou scandaleuse, sans qu'elle représente nécessairement un manque de respect à notre égard, ce qui rendrait l'usage de "outrageant" impropre.